# Getting "Unauthorized Access" with RPC (using Python Requests)

Tags: rpc, monero-wallet-rpc, python

I can successfully do a `getbalance` RPC with digest authentication, e.g.:

```
url = "http://localhost:18082/json_rpc"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
rpc_input = {
       "method": "getbalance"
}
rpc_input.update({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "0"})
response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(rpc_input),
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPDigestAuth('wallet_username', 'wallet_password'))
print(response.text)
```

However, when I want to do a `create_wallet` RPC I get an `Unauthorized Access` HTML response:

```
<html><head><title>Unauthorized Access</title></head><body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1></body></html>
```

E.g.:

```
url = "http://localhost:18082/json_rpc"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
rpc_input = {
        "method": "create_wallet",
        "params": {"filename": "mytestwallet", "password": "mytestpassword", "language": "English"}
}
rpc_input.update({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "0"})
response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(rpc_input),
    headers=headers,
    )
print(response.text)
```

I do notice that the `create_wallet` RPC does not take a wallet username parameter, could this be my problem, or am I missing something else? (Note that at https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet the example does include a `filename` parameter but no `username` parameter).

Comment: In your second request the method is "create wallet" instead of "create_wallet", and the "auth=HTTPDigestAuth('wallet_username', 'wallet_password'))" line is missing. Are these typos or actual mistakes in your code?

Comment: @glv I was actually using `create_wallet` and not `create wallet` without the underscore as per the docs (https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet) - I have fixed this in my question. When I run this second part (with `create_wallet`) and the wallet with `--disable-rpc-login` then the wallet creation succeeds. So I guess my question really becomes, how do I authenticate with HTTPDigestAuth when I don't yet have a `wallet_username` or `wallet_password`? I mean, I am creating the wallet with `create_wallet`, so it wouldn't have these credentials yet.

Answer (score 1):

When digest authentication is activated in the *monero-wallet-rpc* program (with the `rpc-login` option), every RPC request must contain the authentication information.

So your request should be something like:

```
url = "http://localhost:18082/json_rpc"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
rpc_input = {
        "method": "create_wallet",
        "params": {"filename": "wallet_file", "password": "wallet_password", "language": "English"}
}
rpc_input.update({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "0"})
response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(rpc_input),
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPDigestAuth('rpc_username', 'rpc_password'))
print(response.text)
```

There is no relation between the name and password required to connect to the RPC server of the *monero-wallet-rpc* program and the name and password of the wallet file.

They should be different, so that if someone gets to know the credentials of the RPC server (e.g. by reading your configuration file for *monero-wallet-rpc* or by listing the processes running on your machine and seeing what parameters were passed to the `--rpc-login` option), your wallet file is not compromised.